# SQL : Aggregating data that is not in the same place on the table

Tags: sql, aggregation

I would like to calculate a specific duration by substracting two dates that are not on the same record.
Let me illustrate it, i have a table that looks like this :

```
projectid | sectionid | editingStartDate | diffusionEndDate
01        | 01        |   01/01/2022     | null
01        | 02        | null             |  11/02/2022
```

From this i would like to substract the editingStartDate from the diffusionEndDate. And the result would be 42 days. And I don't want to do a CROSS JOIN as i have thousands of records.

Does anyone have a solution ?

PS : Sorry if the question is not clear, it's my first time publishing here, I am not familiar with the formats.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products have their own functions.)

Comment: Columns editingStartDate and diffusionEndDate data type?

Comment: Are you using Oracle, MSSQL etc, is the question.

Comment: Also how do you want to partition the data? Is it the earliest edit date and latest diffusion for a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a projectid has many sectionid (more than the two shown in your example) do you want the days between the earliest editingStartDate and the latest diffusionEndDate? If so:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    projectid CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    sectionid CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    editingStartDate DATE NULL,
    diffusionEndDate DATE NULL
);


INSERT INTO @Table
(
    projectid,
    sectionid,
    editingStartDate,
    diffusionEndDate
)
VALUES
(   '01',       -- projectid - char(2)
    '01',       -- sectionid - char(2)
    '20220101', -- editingStartDate - date
    NULL        -- diffusionEndDate - date
    ),
(   '01',      -- projectid - char(2)
    '02',      -- sectionid - char(2)
    NULL,      -- editingStartDate - date
    '20220211' -- diffusionEndDate - date
);


SELECT projectid,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(editingStartDate), MAX(diffusionEndDate)) + 1 AS Duration
FROM @Table
GROUP BY projectid
ORDER BY projectid;
```

Gives the result:

[image]